# How can pyspark remember something in memory like class attributes in mapreduce?

Tags: pyspark, mapreduce

I have a table with 2 columns: `image_url`, `comment`. The same image may have many comments, and data are sorted by `image_url` in files.

I need to crawl the image, and transfer it to binary. This will take a long time. So, for the same image, I want to do it only once.

In mapreduce, I can remember the last row and result in memory.

```
class Mapper:
  def __init__(self):
    self.image_url = None
    self.image_bin = None
  def run(self, image_url, comment):
     if image_url != self.image_url:
       self.image_url = image_url
       self.image_bin = process(image_url)
     return self.image_url, self.image_bin, comment
```

How can I do it in pyspark? Either rdd and dataframe is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `mapPartitions` works. The code look like this.

```
def do_cover_partition(partitionData):
    last_url = None
    last_bin = None
    for row in partitionData:
        data = row.asDict()
        print(data)
        if data['cover_url'] != last_url:
            last_url = data['cover_url']
            last_bin = url2bin(last_url)
            print(data['comment'])
        data['frames'] = last_bin
        yield data

columns = ["id","cover_url","comment","frames"]
df = df.rdd.mapPartitions(do_cover_partition).map(lambda x: [x[c] for c in columns]).toDF(columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to simply process a grouped version of your dataframe. Something like this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Assuming df is your dataframe
df = df.groupBy("image_url").agg(F.collect_list("comment").alias("comments"))

df = df.withColumn("image_bin", process(F.col("image_url")))

df.select(
    "image_url",
    "image_bin",
    F.explode("comments").alias("comment"),
).show()
```

Comment: agg would take extra cost, I found mapPartitions works. Thanks any way!